# Scala for loop error

Tags: scala

I'm trying to loop through a matrix based on the lat and long given but, when I try to build I am getting this error.

> Error:(55, 21) value foreach is not a member of Range.Partial[Double,scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]]
>             for(i <- lat0 to lat1){
>
> Error:(56, 23) value foreach is not a member of Range.Partial[Double,scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]]
>               for(k <- lon0 to lon1){

Code:

```
  // lat0,lat1,lon0,lon1 are parameters that are type Double
  var count = 0.0;
  var sum = 0.0;

  for(i <- lat0 to lat1){
    for(k <- lon0 to lon1){
      if(this.data(i)(k) != this.noData){
        count += 1.0
        sum += data(i)(k).toDouble
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `lat0`, `lat1`, `lon0` and `lon1` are doubles.

If you do `[Int] to [Int]` it will return `Range.Inclusive` which implements `Iterable` and has `foreach` method: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/collection/immutable/Range$$Inclusive.html

If you do `[Double] to [Double]`, however, `Range.Partial` will be returned, and it's not `Iterable`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/collection/immutable/Range$$Partial.html

If you need to use `for` loop, generate some iterable collection, like `Seq`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a step to iterate `Double` range, e.g. using `by`:

```
  for (i <- lat0 to lat1 by 0.1) {
    for (k <- lon0 to lon1 by 0.1) {
      if (this.data(i)(k) != this.noData) {
        count += 1.0
        sum += data(i)(k).toDouble
      }
    }
  }
```